# Problem in Data Property inference with swrl in protegé

Tags: owl, protege, swrl

I wrote a SWRL rule in this way:

```
Guarani(?g)->AmphibiousSpeed(?g,45)
```

I already have a class Guarani and a data property AmphibiousSpeed. I already created an individual guarani0.

It feels like after reasoning the data property of a should be 45.

However there is no data property for guarani0.

I already enabled the data properties inferences in Preferences and i tested Protegé 5.1 and 5.6 but it is not working.

Comment: Which datatype is set for the range of your property? It might differ from the default one (you didn't specify one in the rule)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question using Pellet reasoner. It is not working with HermiT